# Why are lines with man and news underlined in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

So I ran the command `less < /etc/passwd` in the terminal, and the `/etc/passwd` file is displayed. When I move my cursor over some of the lines (namely the lines beginning with `man` and `news`) were underlined.

Typically, I though this was a link, but clicking or double-clicking on it doesn't do anything.

So why are some of these lines underlined on mouse-over?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is isn't `less` doing this, it's `gnome-terminal` parsing the line as a protocol URI.

It seems `gnome-terminal` has a particularly broad array of "supported" protocols and in these two cases (man and news) you're being incorrectly linked to manpages and NNTP news sites.

I'm fairly sure this is just a bug (the URL is clearly malformed) and other terminal emulators (Terminator and Konsole tested) don't capture `/etc/passwd` lines. However they do parse valid `news://` links. There are many protocols like this.

And (otherwise off-topic) `less` can take a filename; You don't need to redirect into it.
That is to say `less /etc/passwd` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Moved from Windows to Ubuntu, everything is so new and exciting!

Comment: In gnome-terminal it's Ctrl+click that actives these underlined patterns, typically `http://` URLs. In these particular cases, however, it's clear that underlining these are false matches.